# Websocket with codename one

Tags: codenameone

Will be be able to use the same websocket code for JS too? or is there any special code needed depending on platform?

Also will we be able to extend URLImage.createToStorage() method to load from our own websocket based backend rather than from URL? and will it be possible to make it work seamless in all devices?

Comment: I saw your answer below, you should post these things as a comment otherwise we don't get a notification and it isn't an answer so it was deleted by moderation. I can't find your account details so please contact us thru the support email if you'd like assistance with this

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use websockets for the connection from a JavaScript build see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/ln7fMka99iY/cvifdpvkBwAJ). Notice that if you need to connect to a different server from the origin you will need to proxy your request to keep the same origin behavior.

You can't override the create methods of [URLImage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/URLImage.html) as they are all static. You can however download the files thru a websocket and open them using the `EncodedImage.create` method that accepts a byte array.